# Node js middleware for async request to mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

now i am working about my nodejs application. But i have some problem.

So all that i need add avatar field to post objects.

It look something like this.

In mongodb there are 2 model user and post. Post have userId field for one-to-many relationship. And user have avatar were I store string for image tag on the screen.

But I want display all post with user avatar so  that is my home method from controllers/articles.js

```
exports.home = function () {
       Article.list( function (err,articles) {
            _.each(articles, function (item){
               User.find({is:item.id}, function(err, user)
               {
                   item.avatar = user.avatar
               })
        })
    })   
 }
```

But it doesn't work. I understand that it is async problem. But I dont know how to fix it. I don't want change my mongodb structure. And I dont want get all post and all user during each request. So maybe you help me with it. It mast be something with middleware - but i have tried and it does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

underscore.each() would not work for this.  You need to use something like async.each() to make sure you get all the avatars before returning back the result in the response.  Some thing like this (you might need to do some error handling):

```
var async = require('async');
exports.home = function (res) {
   Article.list( function (err,articles) {
        async.each(articles, function (item, callback){
           User.find({is:item.id}, function(err, user) {
               if (user) {
                   item.avatar = user.avatar;
               }
               callback(null); 
           });
        }, function(err) {
            // after finding all avatars, return your articles (with avatars if available)
            // back in the response
            res.send(articles);
        });
    });
};
```